# How do equals and hashCode work under the hood?

Tags: java

I researched this question and the answers I got do not satisfy me as they don't explain these things deeply enough. So, it is known that for HashSet with a parametrized custom class it is necessary to override hashCode and equals in order to forbid duplicates. But in practice when I tried to understand how this really works I didn't quite get it.
I have a class:

```
static class Ball {
    String color;

    public Ball(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Ball ball = (Ball) o;
        return Objects.equals(color, ball.color);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(color);
    }
    }
```

In equals method, it is all clear. If two 'variables' are pointing to the same object in memory, then they are equal; if an o is null or they are not of the same class - they are not equal.
The last line of equals is what's concerning me.
When I go to the Objects.equals :

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

It says once again if two 'variables' refer the same object, then they are equal or if the first object is not null and it is equal to the second one. This equals is Object.equals which will return true if only these two objects aka 'variables' are pointing to the same object in memory.
So, how does this really works? Been looking for a clear answer, but as I said, what I've got so far does not satisfy me at all.

Comment: "This equals is Object.equals which will return true if only these two objects aka 'variables' are pointing to the same object in memory." - that is incorrect. Read that code again.

Comment: `a.equals(b)` <- in your case `a` and `b` are Objects of type `String`. So it will call the `equals` method of the String class.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS But why when I navigate to that method, it redirects me to the Object class?

Comment: I recommend "inlining" that `Objects.equals` call as a exercise. Replace the `Objects.equal` in `Ball.equals` with the implementation of `Objects.equals`. Remember to also replace `a` and `b` with the corresponding arguments. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @Iva_Only_Java because inside of `Object.equals`, the parameters are of type Object. Your IDE does not know that the method is called as `Objects.equals(color, ball.color)`, in which context these parameters are actually `String` variables and thus, `String::equals` is executed. You can try it out by setting a breakpoint and jumping into the `a.equals`.

Comment: @Iva_Only_Java `String` has its own implementation of `equals`: if their contents are the same they are equal. Hence thoses two Strings have different references in memory but are equal nonetheless : `String a = new String("x"); String b = new String("x");`

Comment: @Iva_Only_Java In the snippet of Objects.equals, "Object" is the compile-time type of the parameters. But in your case their runtime-type is String. During execution the methods are invoked on the runtime-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class, you explained it very well.

The part that you are missing is that at some point, your code will delegate to the equals and hashCode on the `color` attribute, which is implemented by the `java.lang.String` class.

See e.g. https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L1013 and https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L1494

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

> return Objects.equals(color, ball.color);

You are passing two `String` objects here, not `Ball` objects.

Your override of `Object#equals` compares `Ball` objects, while the line above compares the `String` objects referenced by the `color` field of `Ball`.

## Details

First, let’s clarify the terminology.

> This equals is Object.equals which will return true if only these two objects aka 'variables' are pointing to the same object in memory.

In your `equals` method, both `this` and `Object o` are reference variables, not objects. Either variable can hold no reference at all (null) or either variable can hold a reference (pointer) to an object living elsewhere in memory.

Next we can examine your code.

### Three Phases of `equals`

The logic of your `equals` is three phased:

- Identity check
- Null check
- Content comparison

The first phase performs an **identity check**. We look to see if both reference variables refer to the same object, the same chunk of memory. If so, there is no need for further consideration: An object is always equal to itself. So return `true`, job done.

The second phase performs a **null check**. If either of the two objects being compared is null, we report `false`, meaning “not equal”. To perform the null check, we skip `this`. The `this` reference variable cannot be null by definition. We move on to the `Object o`. If null, report `false`, job done.

The third phase **compares *content***. We examine the content of the object referenced by `this`. And we examine the content of the object referenced by `Object o`. We know we have two separate objects (two separate chunks of memory) because at this point in the code we got past the identity check.

In your case with the `Ball` class, you chose to compare the one and only piece of state, the member field `color`. That member field holds a reference to a `String` object. So, after casting `o` to `Ball ball`, we compare the string from `this.color` to the string from `ball.color`.

This seems to be the sticking point in your understanding.  The casting is crucial here. After successfully casting from `Object o` to `Ball ball`, the Java Virtual Machine at runtime knows that the object in question is indeed a `Ball` (or a subclass of `Ball`). As a `Ball`, we have access to its `color` field.

In the call to `Objects.equals(color, ball.color)` we are comparing two `String` objects, not two `Ball` objects. You may find clarity in expanding that code.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Ball ball = (Ball) o;
    String thisColor = this.color ; 
    String thatColor = ball.color ; 
    boolean colorsAreTheSame = thisColor.equals( thatColor );
    return colorsAreTheSame ; 
}
```

You said:

> When I go to the Objects.equals :

Your code is passing two `String` objects to `Objects.equal`, not two `Ball` objects.

By the way, do not confuse `Objects.equals` with `Object#equals`.

- This first is a `static` method on the utility class `Objects` — notice the plural `s`.
- The second is an instance method defined on the ultimate superclass `Object` — note the singular, with no `s` on the end.  The second is inherited by `Ball`, but then overridden by the `Ball` class’ own implementation. So **the implementation provided by `Object#equals`** is never used in your scenario.

You said:

> This `equals` is `Object.equals` which will return true if only these two objects aka 'variables' are pointing to the same object in memory.

You cut it short there. The `Object.equals` method performs the same three phased logic as your `equals` method: firstly identity check, secondly null check, and thirdly whatever is implemented in the `equals` method of the two objects.

And most importantly, you are passing two `String` objects to `Objects.equals`, whereas your override of `equals` compares two `Ball` objects.

---

By the way, if the purpose of your class is to communicate date transparently and immutably, you can more briefly define the class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java 16+.

In a record, you merely declare the type and name of each member field. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

The default for this methods is to utilize each and every member field. You can override `equals` & `hashCode` you want to consider a subset of the member fields.

Here is your entire `Ball` class when written as a record.

```
record Ball ( String color ) {}
```

Usage:

```
Ball redBall = new Ball( "red" ) ;
Ball blueBall = new Ball( "blue" ) ;
boolean sameBall = redBall.equals( blueBall ) ;  // false
```